# How to solve a determinant?

Tags: matlab

Please see this matlab script, it won't execute as it has to.

```
>> syms x    
>> A=('[1-x -1 0;-1 3-1.5*x -2;0 -2 5-2*x]')
>>solve(det(A),'x')
```

The answers for x should come

```
0.351
1.605
3.54
```

But it seems there is some sort of error in code which I couldn't find.

Comment: What should the determinant equal to?  Right now, it's only an expression in terms of `x`.  If you want this to have numerical values, you have to set it equal to something.

Answer (score 1):

First, the determinant of a matrix is a number. Not a vector. Hence, the result you state for 'x' cannot be the case.

Second, your matrix 'A' is 'char' not a symbolic expression. Try this:

```
syms x
A = [1-x, -1 0; ...
    -1, 3-1.5*x, -2; ...
    0, -2, 5-2*x];

d = det(A);
solve(d, 'x');
```

You should get

```
>> d =
>> - 3*x^3 + (33*x^2)/2 - (45*x)/2 + 6
```

Now, when you substitute for 'x' you get a real number. For example

```
>> subs(d, 5)
>> ans =
>> -69
```

Comment: after getting d =
>> - 3*x^3 + (33*x^2)/2 - (45*x)/2 + 6 I tried to solve it by using x=solve('- 3*x^3 + (33*x^2)/2 - (45*x)/2 + 6') but instead of the 3 real roots it showed me the imaginary roots. If I take the coefficient of polynomial and run it roots(-3 16.5 -22.5 6) it gives me actual answer. What am I missing here?